# "Can't find variable: google" when using external javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm looking to build a rather simply website that utilizes some functions of Google Maps API. I'm new to web programming so please forgive me if this question is a basic one.

I'm using Ruby On Rails on Cloud9.

So the basic idea is:

1. I have a home page that displays a map. (homepage.html.erb)
2. I have a separate page (call it post) that a user uses to post new stuff. Every time a user posts something new, I would take their address (also provided from the user) and put a marker on the map, on home page. (post.html.erb)
3. I wrote a function called addMarker() which takes in an input and draws a marker at the location provided.
4. In the beginning I used the guide google provided, and put all the initialization and geolocation things in homepage.html.erb, in a  tag. However, I later realized if I put it in there, I cannot access it from post.html.erb. This is why I've made a external js to hold all the functions I plan to use.

Relevant files/snippets are as below:

homepage.html.erb

```
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    #map { height: 100%; }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map" style="height:350px;"></div>

  <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&callback=initMap">
  </script>

</body>
```

post.html.erb

The coordinates are hardcoded right now since I still have to implement geocoding, thats problem for another day ;)

```
<script>
    addMarker({lat: 43.730, lng: -79.430});
</script>
```

external javascript

```
var map;
function initMap() {
map = new window.google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  center: {lat: 43.700, lng: -79.400},
  zoom: 13
});



var infoWindow = new window.google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});

  // Try HTML5 geolocation.
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };

      infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
      infoWindow.setContent('You are here!');
      map.setCenter(pos);
    }, function() {
      handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    });
  } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
  }
  addMarker({lat:43.75, lng:-79.45});
}

function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
  infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
  infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                        'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                        'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
}
function addMarker(pos){
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: pos,
    map: map,
    title: 'FOOD!'
  });
  marker.setMap(map);
}
```

When I first run the application, everything is fine, the map shows up, and the addMarker() call in initMap() works as well. However, when I click through links to get to post.html.erb, and call addMarker there, it says "Can't find variable: google". Also, before I run the program the IDE does warn me about google being undefined but since I didn't know how to fix it I ran it anyways, and initMap() worked so the object google must have had some value. I'm really confused...

The linking to .js works fine since the program is actually in the .js file. (At first I thought it was since I didn't explicitly  but I guess application.js from RoR links it automatically....I guess?)

I have looked at many posts on stack overflow but none of the suggestions seemed to solve my problem. If anyone can provide any suggestions, it would be very appreciated. Thanks in advance!!